# How to make this carousel unreliable on id assigned in props?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I've recently build a carousel with slots. But it has one issue. This component is based on the fact that id for each slide is defined as a prop, so code looks more complicated and I'm sure that there's simpler way to do it.

```
<template>
    <div class="carousel">
        
        <slot class="image"></slot>
        <div class="arrow left" @click="prev"
        :class="{ 'invisible': !hasPrev() }">
        <svg width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <path d="M13.9783 5.31877L10.7683 8.52877L8.79828 10.4888C7.96828 11.3188 7.96828 12.6688 8.79828 13.4988L13.9783 18.6788C14.6583 19.3588 15.8183 18.8688 15.8183 17.9188V12.3088V6.07877C15.8183 5.11877 14.6583 4.63877 13.9783 5.31877Z" fill="#292D32"></path> </g></svg></div>
         <div class="arrow right" @click="next"
         :class="{ 'invisible': !hasNext() }"><svg width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(180)"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <path d="M13.9783 5.31877L10.7683 8.52877L8.79828 10.4888C7.96828 11.3188 7.96828 12.6688 8.79828 13.4988L13.9783 18.6788C14.6583 19.3588 15.8183 18.8688 15.8183 17.9188V12.3088V6.07877C15.8183 5.11877 14.6583 4.63877 13.9783 5.31877Z" fill="#292D32"></path> </g></svg></div>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { provide } from "vue";
export default {
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    const carouselIds = ref(slots.default().map((slide) => slide.props.id));
    const selectedId = ref(carouselIds.value[0]);
    provide("selectedId", selectedId);

    return {
        carouselIds,
        selectedId,
    };
  },
  data(){
    return{
        id:1
    }
  },
  methods:{
    hasNext() {
            return this.id  < this.carouselIds.length;
        },
        hasPrev() {
            return this.id - 1 >=  1
        },
        prev() {
            if (this.hasPrev()) {
                this.selectedId = this.id-=1
            }
        },
        next() {
            if (this.hasNext()) {
                this.selectedId = this.id+=1;
            }
        }
  },

};

</script>
<style scoped>
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.carousel{
    position: relative;

}
.arrow{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


.arrow.right{
    right: 0;
}
.arrow.left{
    left: 0;
}
</style>
```

This is my main Carousel component where each slide is slot inside this Carousel. As you see, by extracting id defined as a prop in each slide component, it creates a new array with each id assigned to each slide in array. By clicking on buttons "next", "prev", it changes id, so it assigns the next slide that has the same id as id that we've incremented.

```
<template>
    <div class="slide" v-show="id == selectedId">

        <slot/>
    </div>
    
</template>
<script>
import { inject } from 'vue';
export default{
    props:['id'],
    setup(){
        const selectedId=inject('selectedId')

        return{
            selectedId,
        }
    },
```

```
  <Carousel>
            <Slide id="1">
<img src="https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/size/w2000/2022/08/Vue-Blog-Cover-2.png">
            </Slide>
            <Slide id="2">
<img src="https://community-cdn-digitalocean-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/snN3rbgKF7McfuiQAKcoLWMn'">
            </Slide >
        </Carousel>
```

I want to somehow extract indices of all elements in my array and then create a new array with these indices, so I can implement the same method without assigning id for each slide.

My code in [SFC playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `Carousel` to be responsible to show / hide sliders depending on the `selectedId`, you could use a [render function](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#basic-usage) to dynamically add a css class to `display` each slider :

```js
import { h } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: {
    selectedId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  render() {
    const slides = this.$slots.default()[0].children
    const render = []
    
    slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
      render.push(h('div', { class: this.selectedId === index ? '' : 'hidden'}, slide))
    })
    
    return render
  }
}
```

I have adapted your [SFC playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) accordingly.

You can also insert slides in the dom only when user is navigating, which would result of a kind of "lazy loading" :

```js
  render() {
    const slide = this.$slots.default()[0].children[this.selectedId]
    
    return h('div', slide)
  }
```

Comment: It really works, you saved my life because I really don't want to use array of images for my own carousel component.

Comment: Glad I could help ! If the solution I provide fits your needs, you can accept the answer. If you have any question about my implementation you can ask.

Comment: Just explain me how to render works in this solution. I think that I have to dive into this feature of Vue a bit deeper because it provides you a freedom in cases like this.

Comment: Yeah render functions are not often used, but they are really powerful and are very handy in such situations. Actually, VueJS internally compile `<template>` in SFC components to javascript like this. Here, you do it by hand. The documentation (as always) is well done !

Comment: I added a small example of "lazy loading" your slides in my answer if it helps you understand a bit more

Comment: Okay, I'm going to use this code for my own project. You made my day